# Split unique values into separate columns for multiple columns

Tags: r, machine-learning, data.table

Each of my data's columns will be rescaled and put into bins from 0 to 100. The bin columns will be used as features for a model. In order to test each bin separately, I'd like to split each bin column into separate columns for each of it's values. The new column will hold either a 0 or 1, dependent upon whether the value in the cell matched the column's bin. From something like this:

```
row values
  1     10
  2     20
  3     30
  4     40
  5     10
  6     30
  7     40
```

to this:

```
row values_10 values_20 values_30 values_40
  1         1         0         0         0
  2         0         1         0         0
  3         0         0         1         0
  4         0         0         0         1
  5         1         0         0         0
  6         0         0         1         0
  7         0         0         0         1
```

This brute force approach does the job, but there must be a better (non-loop) way:

```
values <- c( 10,20,30,40,10,30,40)
dat <- data.frame(values)

columnNames <- unique(dat$values)

for( n in 1:length(columnNames) )
{
    dat[as.character(columnNames[n])]  <- 0
}

columnNames2 <- colnames(dat)

for( c in 2:ncol(dat))
{
    hdr <- columnNames2[c]

    for( r in 1:nrow(dat))
    {
        if( dat$values[r]==as.integer(hdr) )
            dat[r,c]=1
    }
}
```

Many thanks!!

**EDIT**

These are all great answers, thank you everyone. The final object, whether a matrix, table, or data.table, will contain only the separate bin columns (no source columns). How can the solutions below be used for 2000+ source columns?

**EDIT2**

Based on the answers to my follow-up question, below are implementations for each of the methods for anyone coming to this question in the future.

```
# read in some data with multiple columns

df_in  <- read.table(text="row val1 val2
                  1     10     100
                  2     20     200
                  3     30     300
                  4     40     400
                  5     10     100
                  6     30     300
                  7     40     400", header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

#   @Zelazny7 's method using a matrix

df_in$row <- NULL

col_names <- names(df_in)

for( c in 1:length(col_names)){

    uniq <- unlist(unique(df_in[col_names[c]]))

    m <- matrix(0, nrow(df_in), length(uniq), 
                dimnames = list(NULL, paste0(col_names[c], "_", uniq)))

    for (i in seq_along(df_in[[col_names[c]]])) {
        k <- match(df_in[[col_names[c]]][i], uniq, 0)
        m[i,k] <- 1
    }

    if( c==1 )
        df_out <- m
    else
        df_out <- cbind(df_out,m)
}


#   @P Lapointe 's method using 'table'

col_names <- names(df_in)

for( c in 2:length(col_names)){

    m <- table(df_in$row,df_in[[col_names[c]]])    
    uniq <- unlist(unique(df_in[col_names[c]]))
    newNames <- toString(paste0(col_names[c],'_',uniq))

    if( c==2 ){
        df_out <- m
        hdrs <- newNames
    }
    else{
        df_out <- cbind(df_out,m)
        hdrs <- paste(hdrs,newNames,sep=", ")
    }
}

colnames(df_out) <- unlist(strsplit(hdrs, split=", "))


#   @bdemarest 's method using 'data.table'
#   read in data first

library(data.table)

df_in = fread("row val1 val2
            1     10     100
            2     20     200
            3     30     300
            4     40     400
            5     10     100
            6     30     300
            7     40     400")

df_in$count = 1L

col_names <- names(df_in)

for( c in 2:length(col_names)-1){

    m = dcast(df_in, paste( 'row', '~', col_names[c]), value.var="count", fill=0L)

    uniq <- unlist(unique(df_in[,get(col_names[c])]))
    newNames <- toString(paste0(col_names[c],'_',uniq))

    m$row <- NULL

    if( c==2 ){
        df_out <- m
        hdrs <- newNames
    }
    else if( c>2 ){
        df_out <- cbind(df_out,m)
        hdrs <- paste(hdrs,newNames,sep=", ")
    }
}

colnames(df_out) <- unlist(strsplit(hdrs, split=", "))
```

All answers were appropriate and usable so the best answer was awarded to the quickest initial response. Thanks again for your help!!

Comment: look at `?dcast`

Comment: Instead of creating separate dummy columns, you can use `cut` to group a single column of data into factor categories (in this case it looks like you'd want an ordered factor). R's model functions generally create the dummy columns automatically if you include a factor column in your model. If not, you can use `model.matrix` to create the dummy columns. But are you sure it makes sense to group the data? Doesn't that just throw away information?

Comment: This gets you the basic structure of the matrix you are looking for: `df$I = 1;t(tidyr::spread(df, key = row, value = I))`

Comment: @eipi10 Thank you for the suggestions. The actual bins for the rescaled data are 0,1,2,3...100, which is an adequate resolution for this application. I chose 10,20,etc in the example to visually distinguish the 'value' column from the 'row' column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do this quite often. This is the method I use to create dummies. It is very fast.

```
## reading in your example data
df <- read.table(file = "clipboard", header=TRUE)
df$row <- NULL

uniq <- unique(df$values)
m <- matrix(0, nrow(df), length(uniq), dimnames = list(NULL, paste0("column_", uniq)))

for (i in seq_along(df$values)) {
  k <- match(df$values[i], uniq, 0)
  m[i,k] <- 1
}
```

And the results:

```
> m
     column_10 column_20 column_30 column_40
[1,]         1         0         0         0
[2,]         0         1         0         0
[3,]         0         0         1         0
[4,]         0         0         0         1
[5,]         1         0         0         0
[6,]         0         0         1         0
[7,]         0         0         0         1
```

Another variant that avoids the loop by indexing the matrix with a matrix:

```
m[cbind(seq.int(nrow(m)), match(df$values, uniq))] <- 1
```

Comment: Thank you! I like that you've incorporated a method for renaming the columns with a label and the bin. My source data has 2000+ columns and being able to distinguish bin 10 for column A from bin 10 for column B, etc.,  is a must. Can this technique be used across multiple source columns?

Comment: Yes, just replace "column_" in the `paste` function with whatever you want. Such as `var1_`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `table`:

```
df1  <- read.table(text="row values
  1     10
  2     20
  3     30
  4     40
  5     10
  6     30
  7     40", header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

  table(df1)

    values
row 10 20 30 40
  1  1  0  0  0
  2  0  1  0  0
  3  0  0  1  0
  4  0  0  0  1
  5  1  0  0  0
  6  0  0  1  0
  7  0  0  0  1
```

You can index the `table` like this:

```
table(df1)[5,1]
[1] 1
```

**EDIT**
To answer your additional request, you can make new column names like so:

```
tbl <-table(df1)
out<-as.data.frame.matrix(tbl) #to transform into a data.frame
colnames(out) <-make.names(colnames(out)) #to make new column names
out
  X10 X20 X30 X40
1   1   0   0   0
2   0   1   0   0
3   0   0   1   0
4   0   0   0   1
5   1   0   0   0
6   0   0   1   0
7   0   0   0   1
```

Comment: This is great, nice and simple, thank  you! My source data has 2000+ columns, each will be split in this manner. Can your method be modified to include labels in the new column names so the bins from column A would be distinguishable from column B? Also, how can this be applied to multiple columns?

Comment: If by inluding labels, you mean changing the column names, see my edit above.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a `data.table` solution. I first add a `count` column, then reshape to wide form with `dcast()`. By the way, this is fast enough to use on data with 10 million or more rows.

```
library(data.table)

tab = fread("row values
  1     10
  2     20
  3     30
  4     40
  5     10
  6     30
  7     40")

tab$count = 1L

res = dcast(tab, row ~ values, value.var="count", fill=0L)
res
#    row 10 20 30 40
# 1:   1  1  0  0  0
# 2:   2  0  1  0  0
# 3:   3  0  0  1  0
# 4:   4  0  0  0  1
# 5:   5  1  0  0  0
# 6:   6  0  0  1  0
# 7:   7  0  0  0  1
```

Comment: Thank you very much for providing a data.table solution! My source data has 2000+ columns, each will be split in this manner. Can this method be modified to include labels in the new column names so the bins from column A would be distinguishable from column B? Also, how can this be applied to multiple columns?