# Split Columns By Value in Data Table in R

Tags: r, datatable

I'm trying to split out columns in a data table by unique values similar to this: [Split unique values into separate columns for multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42770699)

The issue I'm having is that I have 8 columns instead of 1, and values are repeated across columns (for instance in the example linked above, the value 10 would should up multiple times in each column, but never more than once in a given row).  If the solutions posted above were used, then I would end up with 8 columns for 10, 20, 30, etc., instead of 1, since the value 10 isn't always in the same column for the rows in which it appears.  How can I get only one column for each unique value?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean using the `data.table` package in R? Or more generically a data.frame?

Comment: Could you also share a sample of your data with dput(head(your_data))

Comment: Please add data using `dput` and show the expected output for the same. Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).